# Gnome / Fedora26 Switching Windows is very slow

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, gnome-shell

I'm using Gnome / Fedora 26. When I click "master" key (i.e. Windows button on the keyboard) - I get a preview of all open apps on the screen, and this operation is fast. However switching to another window from such preview takes 2-3 seconds (or even clicking ESC key to get back). Searching for the app on that screen also takes a huge lag before I see

```
Fedora26: 4.12.9-300.fc26.x86_64
Gnome: 2.32.0
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69 driver installed
NVIDIA 980 Graphic card / 4K Asus display
```

---

```
gnome-about --gnome-version

(gnome-about:9120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "hcengine",
Version: 2.32.0
Distributor: Red Hat, Inc
Build Date: 02/10/2017
```